# Ubuntu: Silent install of mssql-tools and unixodbc-dev (automatically accept EULA)

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-16.04

I was trying to install mssql-tools (for sqlcmd and bcp) using `apt-get install` as part of a Dockerfile, but the preinst script kept halting and prompting to accept the EULA.

Is there a way to automatically accept the license for this package?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Turns out you can set `ACCEPT_EULA=Y` in the environment prior to the install command:

```
ACCEPT_EULA=y DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends mssql-tools unixodbc-dev
```

I discovered this by downloading the package `.deb` file, untarring it and looking at the `preinst` script which had this block:

```
check_eula_acceptance()
{
    if [ "$ACCEPT_EULA" != "y" ] && [ "$ACCEPT_EULA" != "Y" ]; then
...
```